# Finding a String from JSON in Dart

Tags: json, dart

I really need to find some information inside a JSON file, in Java I can easily find a string from a JSON Object with

```
JSON_Object.getString("String Here");
```

But I cannot find anything similar in Dart. So far all I can see is:

```
var jsonobject = new JsonObject.fromJsonString(jsonString);
print(jsonobject.something);
```

but the problem with this is that I cannot find a String nested in other bits of JSON. Here is the JSON I am using:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51.4346502,-0.1020349

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: it's a simple json object. So just parse it and get the data you need. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the structure of your JSON you can access it directly

```dart
var json = ...
print(json["results"][0]["formatted_address"]);
```

Answer (score 5):

this is some code that does the trick. You might have to change it a little bit to fit your needs:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  get('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51.4346502,-0.1020349').then((Response response) {
    var json = JSON.decode(response.body);

    json['results'].forEach((result){
      print(result['formatted_address']);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will not accept the answer but I will +1 it because I will be using it later, I really appreciate that answer though